# What am I supposed to specify for "--host" to cross compile gcc from x86_64 for aarch64?

Tags: linux, gcc, arm64

I want to build gcc as mentioned here: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/ for my machine. The build machine is:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- x86_64
- Intel i7

I successfully built gcc 13.1.0 on this machine. Next I want to build the same gcc for the other machine (because that one's much slower and has a lot less RAM).

The host/target machine is (I want to be able to compile C/C++ and run resulting programs here):

- Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 3.0.2 (zeus)
- aarch64
- arm64

Letting the configure script run on the target machine gives: --host=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu

So I run configure with `--build=x86_64-intel-linux-gnu`, `--host=aarch64-arm64-linux-gnu`, which doesn't complain, but when I then run make, it results in error. Scrolling up reveals:

`/bin/bash: line 1: aarch64-arm64-linux-gnu-ar: command not found`

and

`./libtool: line 1115: aarch64-arm64-linux-gnu-ar: command not found`

So what am I doing wrong? How am I supposed to configure it to build gcc for another machine?

Snippet from (https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) below. As for the `cpu-company-system`, that's essentially what I'm struggling with what I'm supposed to put in there. Is company just intel/arm/apple or what?

> Host, Build and Target specification Specify the host, build and
> target machine configurations. You do this when you run the configure
> script.
>
> The build machine is the system which you are using, the host machine
> is the system where you want to run the resulting compiler (normally
> the build machine), and the target machine is the system for which you
> want the compiler to generate code.
>
> If you are building a compiler to produce code for the machine it runs
> on (a native compiler), you normally do not need to specify any
> operands to configure; it will try to guess the type of machine you
> are on and use that as the build, host and target machines. So you
> don’t need to specify a configuration when building a native compiler
> unless configure cannot figure out what your configuration is or
> guesses wrong.
>
> In those cases, specify the build machine’s configuration name with
> the --host option; the host and target will default to be the same as
> the host machine.
>
> Here is an example:
>
> ./configure --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu A configuration name may be
> canonical or it may be more or less abbreviated (config.sub script
> produces canonical versions).
>
> A canonical configuration name has three parts, separated by dashes.
> It looks like this: ‘cpu-company-system’.
>
> Here are the possible CPU types:
>
> aarch64, aarch64_be, alpha, alpha64, amdgcn, arc, arceb, arm, armeb,
> avr, bfin, bpf, cris, csky, epiphany, fido, fr30, frv, ft32, h8300,
> hppa, hppa2.0, hppa64, i486, i686, ia64, iq2000, lm32, loongarch64,
> m32c, m32r, m32rle, m68k, mcore, microblaze, microblazeel, mips,
> mips64, mips64el, mips64octeon, mips64orion, mips64vr, mipsel,
> mipsisa32, mipsisa32r2, mipsisa64, mipsisa64r2, mipsisa64r2el,
> mipsisa64sb1, mipsisa64sr71k, mipstx39, mmix, mn10300, moxie, msp430,
> nds32be, nds32le, nios2, nvptx, or1k, pdp11, powerpc, powerpc64,
> powerpc64le, powerpcle, pru, riscv32, riscv32be, riscv64, riscv64be,
> rl78, rx, s390, s390x, sh, shle, sparc, sparc64, tic6x, v850, v850e,
> v850e1, vax, visium, x86_64, xstormy16, xtensa
>
> Here is a list of system types:
>
> aixversion, amdhsa, aout, cygwin, darwinversion, eabi, eabialtivec,
> eabisim, eabisimaltivec, elf, elf32, elfbare, elfoabi, freebsdversion,
> gnu, hpux, hpuxversion, kfreebsd-gnu, kopensolaris-gnu,
> linux-androideabi, linux-gnu, linux-gnu_altivec, linux-musl,
> linux-uclibc, lynxos, mingw32, mingw32crt, mmixware, msdosdjgpp,
> netbsd, netbsdelfversion, nto-qnx, openbsd, rtems, solarisversion,
> symbianelf, tpf, uclinux, uclinux_eabi, vms, vxworks, vxworksae,
> vxworksmils

Comment: If you intent to _run the compiler_ on the aarch64 system, then you need to already have an environment to cross compile from x86 to aarch64 to compile the compiler. The error message is complaining that you don't have that yet.

Comment: I think you have the ideas of "build" and "host" mixed up.  The idea is that you could compile the compiler on machine A ("build"), run the compiler on B ('host"), and run the compiled code on C ("target").  There's not very many situations where you would want build and host to be different, but it is supported.  Here you want them both to be x86_64. However when you don't specify host, it defaults equal to target.

Comment: @NateEldredge So in my case I want to compile the compiler on machine A ("build"), run the compiler on B ('host"), and run the compiled code on B ("target"). Machine A is x86_64, and machine B is aarch64. I thought it was the other way around, that not specifying target, defaults equal to host.

Comment: Oh, I see.  So then yes, you have to first install a compiler with A=B=x86_64, C=aarch64 first.

Answer (score 1):

The "host" is the machine that gcc, the assembler, and the linker will run on

The "target" is the machine that the code generated by gcc will run on.

So if you want to run gcc on your x86_64 machine to generate binaries that will run on your aarch64 machine, you need host = x86_64 and target = aarch64.

Note that you need *all* the tools for this combo of host an target (assembler and linker as well as gcc -- these are generally part of the binutils package).  You'll also need libraries built for the target to link with.

Comment: No, I want to run gcc on the aarch64 machine to generate binaries for itself. The x86_64 machine I want to use to build gcc because it is much faster and has a lot more RAM. I tried building gcc on the aarch64 machine but it took very long and eventually failed due to being out of memory.

Comment: Then you need two versions of gcc -- one to run on x86_64(host) with aarch64(target), that you use to build the second one that has host=target=aarch64